# Cells in Columns doesn't have same width

Tags: html, css, html-table, frontend, css-tables

I want all of the cells in a column to have same width. number of columns will be changed in future, so the cell with the highest width would be the default width of its respective column.
I hope I have explained my situation here.

Here's my code and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfqhtxpp/).

```css
table.lead-data2 {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
table.lead-data2 th,
table.lead-data2 td {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
table.lead-data2 tr {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-right-color: transparent!important;
  border-left-color: transparent!important;
}
```

```html
<table class="lead-data2" style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="checkbox" id="allcb" name="allcb">
      </th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Class</th>
      <th>Contact No.</th>
      <th>Last Updated</th>
      <th>Follow Up</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="cb[]">
      </td>
      <td>Appy Mccoy</td>
      <td>Pending</td>
      <td>8th A</td>
      <td>8989898989</td>
      <td>31 August 2016</td>
      <td>31 August 2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="cb[]">
      </td>
      <td>Andrew Damon</td>
      <td>Pending for Now</td>
      <td>8th A</td>
      <td>8989898989</td>
      <td>31 August 2016</td>
      <td>31 August 2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" name="cb[]">
      </td>
      <td>Ritesh Shukla</td>
      <td>Confirmed</td>
      <td>8th A</td>
      <td>8989898989</td>
      <td>31 August 2016</td>
      <td>31 August 2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb4" name="cb[]">
      </td>
      <td>Anup gupta</td>
      <td>Pending</td>
      <td>8th A</td>
      <td>8989898989</td>
      <td>31 August 2016</td>
      <td>31 August 2016</td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried table layout fixed property but it doesn't seem to work..
I know there's already many questions related to this stuff but things didn't work out for me.

Comment: why are you using `display: inline-block` for `td` and `th`?

Comment: because If i don't then texts are overflowing and overflow:hidden property hides the data in the cell if the data is long

Comment: that is because you have written `white-space: nowrap` for the table... you would be able to omit that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout

```css
table.lead-data2{
    width: "(100/x)%";
     table-layout: fixed;
    white-space: nowrap;
    
}

table.lead-data2 th, table.lead-data2 td{
    width: "(100/x)%";
     padding: 10px 15px;
}
    
    table.lead-data2 tr{
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-right-color: transparent!important;
    border-left-color: transparent!important;
     width: "(100/x)%";
}
```

```html
<table class="lead-data2" style="overflow-x:auto;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" id="allcb" name="allcb"></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Class</th>
                <th>Contact No.</th>
                <th>Last Updated</th>
                <th>Follow Up</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
             <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="cb[]"></td> 
                <td>Appy Mccoy</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>8th A</td>
                <td>8989898989</td>
                <td>31 August 2016</td>
                <td>31 August 2016</td>
            </tr>  
                <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="cb[]"></td> 
                <td>Andrew Damon</td>
                <td>Pending for Now</td>
                <td>8th A</td>
                <td>8989898989</td>
                <td>31 August 2016</td>
                <td>31 August 2016</td>
            </tr>  
                <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb3" name="cb[]"></td> 
                <td>Ritesh Shukla</td>
                <td>Confirmed</td>
                <td>8th A</td>
                <td>8989898989</td>
                <td>31 August 2016</td>
                <td>31 August 2016</td>
            </tr>  
                 <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb4" name="cb[]"></td> 
                <td>Anup gupta</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>8th A</td>
                <td>8989898989</td>
                <td>31 August 2016</td>
                <td>31 August 2016</td>
            </tr>  
                
               
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

As you need to add width: "(100/x)%";

Comment: Im running code snippet here and it seems to work but it isn't working on my project. after inspecting the code Chrome says Invalid property value.

Comment: oh okay I got it. I had to remove display inline block. Thank you vatsal

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/gd8nzaxL/

I just removed the `display: inline-block;` from your `th`s and `td`s.

Comment: yes.. now texts are overflowing at each other, If I do overflow:hidden then, data gets hidden. Is there anything to do ?

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. by removing white space, the data will flow to the second line. but I have found the solution by putting width: "(100/x)%"; and removing display inline block ..

Answer (score 0):

I think is this that you want  :

```
table.lead-data2{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table.lead-data2 th, table.lead-data2 td{
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
table.lead-data2 tr{
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-right-color: transparent!important;
    border-left-color: transparent!important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I didn't want to bring the data in a cell in second line if its too long.. that will effect the overall design of the table

 by the way I have found my solution. https://jsfiddle.net/vatsal18/bxypmurs/

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you've described sounds like the default behaviour for `<table>` elements. In your css you've given all the `<th>` and `<td>` elements in the table a `display` setting of `inline-block`:

```
table.lead-data2 th,
table.lead-data2 td {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This results in these elements not automatically adjusting their sizes according to the other elements in the same column. Removing the `display: inline-block` (and the `table-layout: fixed;` to prevent cells from overflowing into each other) from the css should result in the correct behaviour, if I've understood your description correctly.

The default `display` value for `<th>` and `<td>` elements is `table-cell` and there shouldn't be many cases where you'd want or need to change this. See the w3schools [CSS display Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)  reference for a basic overview of how different `display` values affect element layout.

Comment: Thank you for your response sir.  but I have found the solution by putting width: "(100/x)%"; and removing display inline block .